# Scraping Google Group page with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, ajax, web-scraping, htmlunit, google-groups

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mobile-social-networking-nepal"));
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000000);
    System.out.println(page.asXml());
    webClient.closeAllWindows();


    }
```

I have written the above code for scraping the google group page given by the above URL without any Luck. What I get is empty div and span elements. I have tried it with other URLs and works fine but with google groups page it doesn't seem to work. And further it takes brutally long to get even the undesired output. Help needed.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if they went rich web client, and the initial render of the page is essentially blank, with AJAX calls to fill in all the data.

Answer (score 0):

instantiate webclient as below, it worked for me :

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
```